# Is there a special name in the US for round/hollow neoprene door seals like these?

Tags: doors, sound-proofing, weatherstripping

I know I run the risk of posting a "shopping" question, but I don't know of any other place to go for this.

I am looking to create a custom door gasket to do around a new soundproof door I made.  I find strips like what you see below when I search for things like "neoprene door gasket" and "round neoprene" and what have you, but I only seem to be able to locate these items on overseas websites like China and the UK.  Are neoprene rubber door seals not popular in the US or does they carry a different name?  I'd love to be able to run down to my local Menard's, Home Depot, or Lowe's and pick up some of this stuff, but it seems like it simply doesn't exist here.

What are some terms I could search for to locate these door seal strips in the US?

I especially like the first P-shaped one:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identification in order, P, Half-Round and Quarter-Round

Referred to as door seal or weatherstrip.

Commonly available for aircraft door seal and older automotive trunk and door weatherstrip.

You can get EPDM variants for home door seal use from WeatherKing or MD.

The larger stuff used in automotive can be obtained by the roll from industrial supplies like Grainger.

The US has largely abandoned this stuff as it's easy to snag, miserable to mount and unless made from EPDM rubber, not long lived in sunlight.

The vinyl clad "V" seals that replace it for door casement sealing need only a narrow saw kerf (hence their other name, "Kerf Seal") to be pushed into for mounting, no weatherstrip cement to get all over the place or peal off tacky tape that quits sticking to the surface so it falls off.

[image]

With proper construction so it has full contact and proper compression, it is both air-tight and sound-tight. When worn or damaged, replacement is easy, just gently pull from the slot and press the new strip back in.

You also might search for kerf seal weatherstripping (Amesbury is one such manufacturer) as there are a lot of other cross-sections available that might be more what you're looking for. Having to just cut a slot and have it both readily available and easily replaceable via saw slot is something that will be desirable down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the provider that I use for gaskets, look at the bottom of the page, it has what you are looking for so it seems.[Still new at this...](http://www.conservationtechnology.com/building_gaskets.html)

http://www.conservationtechnology.com/building_gaskets.html

Check further into the site, there are silicone compression bulbs that may suit your need too. They fit into a milled slot and need no means of attachment other than using a screen roller to press it into the groove made by a slot cutter or the special tool the same company will sell you. We had one for retrofitting the silicone bulb into existing door jambs.